# Use only bumper ads in YouTube?

Tags: youtube, youtube-channel

I'm managing a YouTube channel and we want to show only 6-seconds non-skipable adds (aka [Bumper Ads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UyGA.png)), but YouTube only allows me to select [overlay ads, sponsored cards, and Skippable video ads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6ce5.png).

Is there a way to display only bumper ads?